# Sparse coding in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm looking for a library which implements the most common sparse coding and dictionary learning algorithms with a python interface, any suggestion?

Comment: Google turned up http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jiayq/sparsecoding.html and  ahttp://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/google/gsoc2011/vladn/11001 as the top two hits.  What's wrong with these?  Please provide specific problems that make the top Google hits unacceptable.

Comment: ? I do not get it looking at google "sparse coding python", but thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding this question;
seems that a library which implements most of Sparse Coding algorithms  is SPAMS
http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/
which now offers Python support

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty broad question. Among sparse coding, dictionary learning, and nonnegative factorization, there are plenty of methods, many of which are still so new that there does not yet exist a dominant piece of Python software that is universally accepted.

These research areas have been my recent focus, and I primarily use Python. I just decided to write my own simple versions of matching pursuit, NMF (and nonnegative LS), KSVD, and more. I might recommend doing the same for your specific purposes; they are not difficult to implement and modify. Just get used to Numpy, Scipy, and `numpy.linalg`.

That said, there are publicly available Python tools, but you will need to search more specifically. For instance, "matching pursuit python" yields a few results.

For those with convex optimization formulations, you could use CVX which is really easy to use, but you may not find it fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I guess these are answers if (a) you didn't find them and (b) there's nothing wrong with them.

http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jiayq/sparsecoding.html

http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/google/gsoc2011/vladn/11001

Comment: Both links don't work !

Answer (score 0):

I use MPTK ("the Matching Pursuit Toolkit") - http://gforge.inria.fr/projects/mptk/ - there are some python wrappers in the code, but I don't know how stable they are. Personally I just use Python wrappers around the commandline utilities, because in my case the data is usually on disk rather than in memory so there's no big drawback to the loose coupling.